# How does Yugabyte handle single disk failure?

Tags: yugabytedb

I want to know what is the behavior of Yugabyte in case of single disk failures. Specifically:

1. What procedure should the sysadmin follow while dealing with a single disk failure? e.g. does stopping the TServer momentarily, changing the disk and restarting it automatically copy that disk's tablets from other TServers?
2. Does a TServer automatically detect a disk failure and spread the data on that disk to other disks if the failed disk is not replaced within a stipulated time frame?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> What procedure should the sysadmin follow while dealing with a single disk failure? e.g. does stopping the TServer momentarily, changing the disk and restarting it automatically copy that disk's tablets from other TServers?

Yes, the following procedure works, YugabyteDB would recognize the data was missing and rebuild the data:

- Stop the tservers
- Replace the disks
- Restart the tservers

You can try this in a sandbox-like environment on your laptop using `yb-ctl` in case you want to understand this behavior. The setup/procedure is the same as this [fault-tolerance experiment](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/fault-tolerance/). Instead of removing nodes, simply `stop` a node, delete one or more "disks" (which are really just directories) and `start` the node back. I believe there are two disks created by default.

Here is the [manual for `yb-ctl`](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-ctl/).

PS: If you're doing this exercise, please consider contributing to the [fault-tolerance section on docs](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/fault-tolerance/), would be happy to help you if you're interested.

> Does a TServer automatically detect a disk failure and spread the data on that disk to other disks if the failed disk is not replaced within a stipulated time frame?

Yes, this is done automatically if there are enough other nodes to replicate data on. For example:

- **In a single-zone setup with replication factor 3:** if you started with 4 nodes or more, then there would be at least three nodes left after one failed. In this case, re-replication is automatically started if a tserver is down for 10 minutes.
- **In a multi-zone setup with replication-factor 3:** YugabyteDB will try to keep one copy of data per zone. In this case, for automatic re-replication of data, a zone needs to have at least two tservers so that if one fails, its data can be re-replicated to the other. Thus, this would mean at least a 6 node cluster.